# Re-using flow-type class declaration

Tags: flowtype

If I declare a class `C` in a given module, how can it be re-used in a different module?

For instance, a module declares and uses the following:

```
declare class IRecord<T: Object> {
  constructor(irecordValues: $Shape<T>): void;

  inspect(): string;
}
```

However, in a separate module I would like to do the equivalent to:

```
import type { IRecord } from 'other-module';

declare class IRecordState<T: Object, J: Object> extends IRecord<{
}
```

Unfortunately, it is illegal to export the class declaration above and I cannot create an actual (`IRecord`) class because it exists as an untyped entity.  Is the only way to go to create a `.flow.js` module?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by moving the class type declaration into a separate `.js.flow` module and placing this in a directory specifically for flow type-related declarations.  Also had to tweak flow's configuration file so as to instruct it to include these extra declarations. Configuring flow was straightforward and required creating a `.flowconfig` file in the project's root with the following setting:

```
[include]
flow-typed
```

... where `flow-typed` is the directory containing flow type declarations.

Now the class declaration is available throughout the project which makes reusing it possible, however the global presence of this declaration (and others that may be added) is undesirable.